# FOSUserBundle 1.3 ignoring BaseUser fields

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I was using FOSUserBundle 2.0 without any problems (using ORM).  I wanted to add SonataUserBundle so that required me to bump FOSUserBundle back to 1.3 (per https://packagist.org/packages/sonata-project/user-bundle).  However, it no longer works.

In particular, none of the BaseUser fields are being created in the DB when I run the fixtures.  I have verified that I am doing everything according to the tutorial at https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.3.x/Resources/doc/index.md using the Doctrine ORM User class.

FYI, I am using Doctrine annotations, just like the tutorial.

I am stumped.  Any help is appreciated.